# A NULL object in a List stays NULL even after initialization

Tags: c#, class, object, reference, nullreferenceexception

Please take a look at the code below:

```
public class MainClass
{
    MyClass myObject1, myObject2;

    public MainClass()
    {
        myObject1 = new MyClass();
        myObject1.otherObjectsOfSameClass = new List<MyClass> { myObject2 };

        myObject2 = new MyClass();
        myObject2.otherObjectsOfSameClass = new List<MyClass> { myObject1 };
        
        myObject2.otherObjectsOfSameClass[0].TestMethod(); // works fine
        myObject1.otherObjectsOfSameClass[0].TestMethod(); // throws null reference exception
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public List<MyClass> otherObjectsOfSameClass;

    public bool TestMethod()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to store several objects of MyClass type that hold references to the other members of the same type. When I initialize the otherObjectsOfSameClass list of each object in the MainClass constructor, I add the other object to that list. When I initialize the myObject1, the myObject2 is still null - that is expected. The list should hold a reference to myObject2, even if it's null.

However, even after I initialize myObject2, it is still null in the otherObjectsOfSameClass list of the myObject1. For some reason, the object reference in that list doesn't update. Can someone please explain this behavior? Am I misunderstanding something fundamental here?

EDIT: I realized this can be reproduced with an even simpler test code:

```
        List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass> { myObject1, myObject2 };

        myObject1 = new MyClass();

        myObject1.TestMethod(); // works fine
        myList[0].TestMethod(); // throws null reference exception
```

It seems that adding an uninitialized object to a list and initializing it afterwards doesn't change it in the list - even though it should be added by reference, not by value...

Comment: `myObject2` is not initialized, so you have `myObject1.otherObjectsOfSameClass = new List<MyClass> { null };`so the exception... even if you create one that you assign to `myObject2` after, you have null in the list.

Comment: The list item and the variable no longer referred to the same object the moment you reassigned the variable. Variables and lists hold values, and sometimes those values are references. Sometimes two variables, two list items, or a mix, hold the same value, which can be a reference to the same object. But reassigning one does not impact the other.

Comment: Got it. So I just have initialize these objects before adding them to lists, an easy fix. Thank you very much, guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables and elements of lists store values. For a reference type like `MyClass`, That value is either a reference to an *object*, or the value `null` - nothing.

In the working case,

```
myObject2.otherObjectsOfSameClass = new List<MyClass> { myObject1 };
```

The list contains the reference that the variable `myObject1` stores. `myObject1` stores a reference to a `MyClass` object, not null, so the list also stores a reference to that same object, so when you access the list, no exceptions. Note that the values of `myObject1` and `myObject2.otherObjectsOfSameClass[0]` are unrelated. It *just so happens* that their values are references to the same object, but otherwise changing the value of one of them would not affect the other. For example, doing:

```
myObject1 = null;
```

would not make `myObject2.otherObjectsOfSameClass[0]` null as well.

OTOH, when this is run:

```
myObject1.otherObjectsOfSameClass = new List<MyClass> { myObject2 };
```

`myObject2` stores `null`, so the list stores null. Again, the values of `myObject2` and `myObject1.otherObjectsOfSameClass[0]` are unrelated. It just so happens that they are both null. Then you say:

```
myObject2 = new MyClass();
```

which changes the value of `myObject2` to a reference to an object. This has no effect on the value of `myObject1.otherObjectsOfSameClass[0]`. After all, they are two different variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for such an elaborate explanation. I get it now. I just thought that even an uninitiated but declared object already has a pointer which should be passed to that list. All is clear now. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sweeper when you say "It just so happens that their values are references to the same object, but otherwise changing the value of one of them would not affect the other. For example, doing:

myObject1 = null;"

In this example, you are removing the reference, not updating the object.  Try actually setting some property on myObject1 and it will update `myObject2.otherObjectsOfSameClass[0]`  as well

Comment: @cloudComputer107 If you are setting some property of `myObject1`, you are not "changing the value stored in `myObject1`". To change the value of a variable, you should use `=` on that variable, i.e. `myObject1 = ...`. `myObject1.SomeProperty = ...` is changing the value of `SomeProperty`. It has nothing to do with the value of `myObject1`. You are mutating the object referenced by the reference stored in `myObject1`, though.

Comment: Yes you are mutating it, which is why I think it is confusing to say that the values are unrelated

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense - when you initialize `myList = new List<MyClass> { myObject1, myObject2 };` at this time you are creating a new list, and the value in that list will evaluate to null.  The fact that you initialize myObject1 or myObject2 later on will not change the fact that you have nulls stored in myList.

This is because myObject1 is null at the time of instantiation - there is no memory address that it is pointing to, no object that it is referring to.  If, on the other hand, you were to initialize `myObject1 = new someObject()` and then initialize `myList`, it will not be undefined and there will be a reference to myObject1 such that if you update myObject1 the update will also be reflected in `myList`

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. I thought that even a null object still has a memory address, but that memory is just not used yet. So, considering my example, I guess I should first initialize both myObject1 and myObject2, and only then add them to each other's lists?